# How to remove a texture from one side of a cube in Unity 5?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building a visual city in Unity 5 and I used some textures for my buildings. But the problem is whenever I adjust a texture a cube ,it sets all of the sides of the cube to that texture.. I mean I want to remove the roof side texture because there's no building in the real world which has windows on the roof ! *As you can see in this image:*

[image: print screen]

So how can I remove texture from the top side ?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is right. And there is another way to achieve that is **add a plane on the top of the cube**.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you're going to have to do something called UV mapping.

Short answer is that this isn't possible with a regular cube in Unity, you're either going to have to create your own model, or some code to generate a mesh within Unity

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/306959/uv-mapping.html

Comment: Daniel, true enough, but it is "inconceivable" a beginner would be able to do anything like this.  This is a problem with Unity3D questions on this site - there is a *truly vast* range of experience systems within Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Either you know how to manipulate atlas texture or the simple call is to

- Place a quad on top of that face of the cube (you could actually make a new cube of 5 quads or less)
- Cut the part of the atlas map
- Create a new texture and assign it to a material
- Apply that material to the quad.

Then you can swap the texture of that material without affecting other faces.